# Zero-lag butterworth filter?

Tags: filtering

Recently, I've read several papers where zero-lag Butterworth filters are used.

I have a fair understanding of (Butterworth) filters, but how can we design one with **zero** lag? Can someone explain me how this works?

From my understanding, any low-pass filter yields an intrinsic delay.

Or does this involve bidirectional filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked the question on DSP (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/zero-lag-butterworth-filtering). Several answers have been given there..